# Rails partial's local variable doesn't get set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I'm confused with passing a controller's instance variable to a partial template (named after this instance variable).

Documentation from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html says:

*By default PartialRenderer uses the template name for the local name of the object passed into the template. These examples are effectively the same:*

```
<%= render :partial => "contract", :locals => { :contract  => @contract } %>
<%= render :partial => "contract" %>
```

But in my case I can't get the same magic.

*ProductsController#show*:

```
@foo = "123456789"
```

*show.html.erb* in the following edition **works** (controller's *@foo* appears as local variable *foo* in the *_foo.html.erb*):

```
<%= render :partial => 'foo', :locals => { :foo  => @foo } %>
```

But next code **doesn't pass** the controller's @foo variable to the *_foo.html.erb* partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'foo' %>
```

Why so?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, locals usually have to be passed explicitly to the partial. The only case in which it may be passed automatically is when you're passing the main object for that controller action, i.e. if you are passing the record @foo in some action for the foos controller.

In your specific case, passing `@product` should work automatically. If you want to pass `@foo`, you'll need to pass it explicitly.

Comment: The book I have (Agile Web Development with Rails) says: *If the object to be passed to the partial is in a controller instance variable with the same name as the partial, you can omit the :object parameter.* Looks like there is a way to auto-pass instance variables, but somehow obscured.

Comment: @jdoe - only, as it says, if you are passing @foo to the partial `_foo` within the foos controller! Most of the time though, if you want to pass `foo` within the context of products, you'll need to specify.

Comment: RoR Guides says: *In previous versions of Rails, the default local variable would look for an instance variable with the same name as the partial in the parent. This behavior was deprecated in 2.3 and has been removed in Rails 3.0.* It seems there is inconsistency between different sources -- some of them have forgotten about reflecting last changes.

Comment: @jdoe - indeed, the Rails docs are not always perfectly updated and/or consistent, because they are written by a collection of contributors.